# How to get the decibel reading from an iPhone microphone

Tags: iphone, core-audio, microphone

What is the simplest way to get the decibel levels from an iPhone's microphone? I would prefer not to use AVAudioRecorder. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this [sample code](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#samplecode/aurioTouch/Introduction/Intro.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/DTS40007770) from Apple.